# Should I use encryption or hashes for generating custom reference ids?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I need to generate unique custom reference ids for each user based on their user id. Right now I'm using the md5 method for this and have limited the length to 12 digits/characters.

```
$user_id = '120';
$ref_id = substr(md5($user_id, 0, 12);
```

I know there are many ways to generate a string from another string, but what would be the best way to generate a simple but unique user ID with a relatively short length (max. 16 chr/digits)?

The ID is used to preserve and mask the true user ID or the name of the user in publications.

Comment: Why limit it to 12 characters? There are plenty of strings that will have the same first 12 characters in an `MD5` hash. MD5 is not unique anyway so you might as well at least use the whole hash.

Comment: What is your use case? What are you actually trying to protect the data from?

Comment: *The ID is used to preserve and mask the true user ID or the name of the user in publications* a savvy user would see its an md5, and make a hashtable, enter the hash and get the id back.. if you want something better with salting etc as its a number. look into [hashids](https://hashids.org/),

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if the OP insists on slicing the MD5 to x characters long then it can be obscured but will greatly increase the source collision....

Comment: @RealJohnDoe why not just use their ID number? That doesn't give away any details as to *who* that id number is. Like on this question you can find my StackOverflow Id number but that won't give you my email address......

Comment: I love the colors of rainbow tables.

Comment: @Martin Because user ids do not have the same scheme and are sequential. I want all of my users to have let’s say a 16 chr/digit but unique ref ID. It's not really about security, but here the uniqueness is in the foreground. I just selected MD5 for the staging server. I am open for any other advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why not just use their ID number?

> Because user ids do not have the same scheme and are sequential. I want all of my users to have let’s say a 16 chr/digit but unique ref ID. It's not really about security, but here the uniqueness is in the foreground. I just selected MD5 for the staging server. I am open for any other advice.

From the conversation in comments, a good solution would be to generate a unique random key and associate it with the value (such as the database row).

This random key is neither an encryption or a hash. This key is a **unique reference variable**.

So for each user you have their database membership row, and one column would be "reference_key"; this can be populated when a unique value associated only with this account,

## For Example

The below code will generate a unique key and save it to the array value `$saver['reference_key']`  , you can then insert this into your database when you save your other customer data.

The MySQL column should be `UNIQUE` indexed and `UTF8mb4` collation and character set.

The reason that the testing checks if the value exists already would be its easier to re roll the value before the MySQL error is triggered when an identical value is tried to be inserted into the UNIQUE column.

```
function nonce_generator($length = 40)
{
    // Source can be any valid characters you want to use. 
    $source = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzANCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!-=+';
    $max = strlen($source) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    $output = "";
    do {
        $output .= $source[random_int(0,$max)];
        $i++;
    }
    while($i < $length);
    return $output;
}
```

...

```
do {
   $found = false;
   $saver['reference_key'] = nonce_generator(12); //see function above to generate a key. 
   $check = $dataBase->getSelect("SELECT COUNT(*) as numb FROM customer WHERE reference_key = ? ", $saver['reference_key']);
   if ($check['numb'] > 0) {
       // check if key already exists in the database. 
       $found = true;
   }
unset($check);
} while ($found === true);

// once a unique key has been found then save this to the database user. 
// along with all other user details. 
$dataBase->arrayToSQLInsert("customer", $saver);
```

*Please note that for this  code uses customised database interactions and is for illustration purposes ONLY*

## Advantages:

- Unique key does not reference any other customer data.
- Unique key is not a hash or encryption so can not be 'compromised'.
- Key is assured to be unique.

## Disadvantages:

- On very large data sets the `do/while` process of finding a unique value may cause a slight slowdown

Comment: Why does this get a downvote? Care to elaborate?